# How to determine the minimum value of a 4th order polynomial without using calculus?

Tags: maxima-minima

I have got a $4^{th}$ order polynomial, $$x^4+100x^2−2000x+10^4=f(x)$$ whose minimum value I need without using calculus. Is there any way except graph plotting?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. *How* is $x^4+100x^2-2000x+10^4 = d^2$ supposed to be a polynomial? This is an equality between two polynomials with distinct variables.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry edited

Comment: Another thing: in which way is your question a question about `linear-algebra`?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you can get rid of the huge coefficients by transforming to $y=\frac x{10}$, leading to $f(x)=10^4(y^4+y^2-2y+1)=10^4g(y)$ with $g(y)=y^4+y^2-2y+1$.

If $z$ is the minimum value of $g(y)$, the quartic polynomial $h(y)=g(y)-z=y^4+y^2-2y+1-z$ has a multiple root. A quartic polynomial has multiple roots exactly if its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots) is zero. The discriminant of $h(y)$ is

$$
-16(16z^3-40z^2+69z-17)\;.
$$

Thus the minimum value $z$ is the only real zero of the cubic polynomial $16z^3-40z^2+69z-17$, which is

$$
z=\frac1{12}\left(10-\frac{107}{\sqrt[3]{(174\sqrt{87}-1187}}+\sqrt[3]{(174\sqrt{87}-1187}\right)\approx0.28927\;.
$$

Multiply this by $10^4$ to get the minimum value of approximately $2892.7$ of $f(x)$.

Comment: thank you, that is what i got when i used calculus.